# What are some things that can cause session cookies to fail/disappear client-side? How can I make my session system more robust?

Tags: session, cookies

I have a very straightforward session system on my website: User logs in and the response on success contains a session token. The session token is then stored as a cookie with no expiry (`expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT`) and root path (`path=/`).

On requests which require authentication, the client will send the session token value as part of the message, and as a fallback, also as a header and cookie.

Even so, from time to time I get users that just lose their sessions. Their session tokens are still valid, and they haven't logged out. All of a sudden, they apparently don't have the session cookie anymore. They were able to make requests for a while, and for many thousands of requests a day this happens maybe once every day or two so it's a rare occurrence. The requests don't seem to be malicious, they're just normal users who have the website open for a while and suddenly lose auth.

What are some things that can cause this (I expect in at least some cases it's some odd browser/OS setting out of my control)? What are some ways I can prevent this from happening without necessarily knowing the cause?

Comment: Prevent it from happening without knowing the cause? This is very unlikely. I interpret from what you have written that the session id is part of the URL for every request requiring authentication. If so, then it suggests that the problem could be on the server side and it would be helpful if you shared more information as to what your platform/language/infrastructure is. But consider this: On requests not requiring authentication where you do not add the session id to the URL, you are now relying exclusively on the cookie to maintain the id of the user until authentication is needed. (more).

Comment: So this is not quit as robust as you think (although admittedly in a perfect world it should be adequate).

Comment: I would guess that the user cleared his cookies and other browser data for some reason that has nothing to do with your site.  There's nothing you can do about that, but you can make it easy for him to re-login without losing context in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google Chrome, Firefox and other browsers plan to abandon cookies in near future [source1](https://techcrunch.com/2020/01/14/google-wants-to-phase-out-support-for-third-party-cookies-in-chrome-within-two-years/), here is what you need to know. about GDPR and why so.

> EU’s General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) to let users from inside Europe control the activation of cookies and trackers that collect their personal data.

this could be a pain for companies eating cookies. because of the strict legal atmosphere for cookies these days.

a more robust Method to store persistent client side data is discussed here, you can even store whole databases via these methods discussed in MDN webpage. MDN=Mozilla developer Network.

- **Client-side storage**: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage)
- **Web Storage API** : [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)
- **IndexedDB** : [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)
- **LocalStorage** : [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (next best alternative for cookies)

Highlights of LocalStorage API:

localStorage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened. ie system reboot does not affect it.

- Stores data with no expiration date, and
- gets cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser cache / Locally Stored Data.
- Storage limit is the non limiting around 5MB!

Comment: Thanks! Still not clear to me why the session cookies are being unintentionally lost, but localStorage seems like a good fallback to make it more stable!

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps redirecting domains? So for example: you SET the cookie ok productlogin.com and you redirect to product.com or any other server where you then want to READ the cookie? Because that won't work.

It could also be that your app is requesting the wrong cookie. Are you matching the same session? It could help us if you have some code to share.